# Why won't my outdoor motion detector shut off?

Tags: lighting, outdoor

I have had 2 outdoor motion detectors on each side of the front door for approximately 5 years. They worked fine. Suddenly one of them refuses to go off. The other one continues to work fine. I tried a different bulb, and turning it off and then on again, but it hasn't helped.

Since it worked before, and the other one is still working, I am thinking it's not the wiring. Any thoughts? Do sensors go bad?

Answer (score 1):

If you have had any lightning in the area it can leave the sensor in the always on mode. Some sensors I have used require a 5 minute powered off cycle to reset them. A power surge,spike or blip can also fry the electronics. I also had a unit that came on even in the day light. It turned out to be a mudwasp nest covering the photosensor.